# Insert into table from temp table using dynamic SQL; Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, temp-tables

I'm working on a SQL Server stored procedure.

This is the part of code which works:

```
INSERT INTO [MYBASE].dbo.[DatabaseName]
    ([Employee No_], [From Date], [To Date], [Description], [Quantity],[First Name], [Last Name])   
    SELECT 
        EmployeeNo, FromDate, ToDate, Description, Quantity, 
        FirstName, LastName 
    FROM 
        #User_Data
```

Now, I need to change this part:

```
INSERT INTO [MYBASE].dbo.[DatabaseName]
```

where `DatabaseName` will be variable.

I've tried with this:

```
CREATE TABLE #User_Data 
(
    User_id INTEGER,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    LastName VARCHAR(30),
    EmployeeNo VARCHAR(20),
    Description VARCHAR(50),
    FromDate DATETIME,
    ToDate DATETIME 
)

INSERT INTO #User_Data
    SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.employee_no,  ... (this works)

DECLARE @InsertStatement VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @InsertStatement =
     'INSERT INTO [MYBASE].dbo.[' + @DatabaseName + ']
               ([Employee No_], [From Date], [To Date], [Description],
                [Quantity], [First Name], [Last Name])   
          SELECT 
              EmployeeNo, FromDate, ToDate, Description,
              Quantity, FirstName, LastName 
          FROM 
              #User_Data'   

    EXEC(@InsertStatement)
```

but it does not work. This is the error I'm getting:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Please help.

Comment: Why would you have a separate table for each "database", rather than one table with "database" as a column name?

Comment: Do you have a table named 'database'?

Comment: No, I don t have a table named 'database'. My bad, sorry. Instead of 'DatabaseName' goes real name of a table.

Comment: As Gordon was pointing out, the biggest issue here is your architecture. Why do you need a separate table for each value of database? It should instead be a column in one table. Then this whole problem becomes trivial. You could skip the dynamic sql, skip the temp table. It would be as simple as a single insert statement.

Comment: Where is the part of the code where you populate `@DatabaseName`?   What do you see when you PRINT your `InsertStatement` before the EXEC?

Comment: Even if you keep the current architecture I would eliminate the temp table. It is not providing any tangible benefit but it does make this more complicated than it needs to be. Just use your select statement that populates the temp table in the final insert statement. You really don't need multiple copies of this data just to insert it elsewhere.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Create a "real" table and tag a set of rows with a SomeTagKey that groups those rows into one set..........

Comment: What is the data type of  [Employee No_] column of [MYBASE].dbo.['+@DatabaseName+']? and the other way, are you using SQL Server 2012 or 2008?

Comment: Thanks. I had some code from before, now I ve corrected it. I don't use temp table anymore, but still have the same problem.
I'm using SQL Server 2012. Employe No is NVARCHAR(20)

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this with Synonyms to avoid having to write within quotes:

```
Declare @MyDB as nvarchar(100) = 'myDBName'

if exists(select * from sys.synonyms where name = N'TableinMyDB') drop synonym [TableinMyDB];
exec('CREATE SYNONYM [TableinMyDB] FOR [' + @MyDB + '].dbo.[myTableName];');

 INSERT INTO [TableinMyDB]
               (
                [Employee No_]
               ,[From Date]
               ,[To Date]
               ,[Description]
               ,[Quantity]
               ,[First Name]
               ,[Last Name]
               )   

        SELECT 
               EmployeeNo 
               ,FromDate 
               ,ToDate
               ,Description
               ,Quantity
               ,FirstName
               ,LastName 
                FROM #User_Data
```

Comment: In my code it is. I only use the synonym after dropping and recreating. I also drop after using. There is no chance of assuming a synonym!

Comment: Thank you, I ll try it like this.